# How can I put a time-delayed lock on a node?

Tags: nodes, workflows

I'm using Drupal 7, and would like to add a time-delayed lock to a specific node type: when a node of that type is created, the creator of the node has fifteen minutes to edit that node. The node then locks and its state changes in workflow.module.

What's the best way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/user_alert is a good module combined with "Job scheduler" or a trigger module for timing should be Fine. but you may have to get creative with the setup. also try http://drupal.org/project/notifications